# Dart PaperDropdownMenu getting selected item

Tags: dart, polymer, paper-elements

I'm kind of struggling getting the selected item id or even the text displayed in a dropdown menu list. Here's my code:

```
HTML:
      <paper-dropdown-menu  label="Currency" on-core-select="{{selectCurrency}}">
        <paper-dropdown class="dropdown" halign='right'>
          <core-menu class="menu"  selected="{{selectedCurrency}}">
            <template repeat="{{c in currencies}}">
              <paper-item>{{c}}</paper-item>
            </template>
          </core-menu>
        </paper-dropdown>
      </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Dart:

```
void selectCurrency(CustomEvent e, var detail, PaperDropdownMenu m) {
    var id = m.getAttribute("selected");
    //id = mCurrencyDropdown.selected;
    JsObject detail = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(e)['detail'];

    if(detail['isSelected']) {
        PaperItem selected =  detail['item'] as PaperItem;

        print( 'source | $selected' );
    }

  print(detail);

}
```

I can see several properties from which I might get the information I want but I can't access them as the don't seem to be public:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-4jVIpB0XuTXJ5eVBMZllyanM/view

Any idea? Thank you!

**Thanks to Günter I have found the answer:**

I have an observable like this:

```
@observable int selectedCurrency = 20;
```

Apparently you can simply add a method to your class matching the members name like this and it's called each time the observable is changed:

```
selectedCurrencyChanged(var oldValue, var newValue) { 
    print(newValue);
}
```

[Official Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the field selectedCurrency you have bound to ?

I guess you can drop the `on-core-select` event handler entirely and instead add a method

```dart
selectedCurrencyChanged(newValue) { 
  // event handler code here 
}
```

Comment: Its bound to an int indicating the currently selected currency: @observable int selectedCurrency = 20; Is the binding bi directional?

Comment: Alright thank you very much! Adding the method with two arguments worked flawlessly. I've been searching the docs for hours without stumbling across a functionality like this. I'm going to update my post with a more detailed description.